# $_SESSION as a local variable

Tags: session, variables

I have a problem with a $_SESSION. I do a POST and i modify the value of $_SESSION['lang'] but this modification is only local (my var_dump($_SESSION); has the good value), but out of this file my variable didn't change.

Do you have any ideas for resolve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I got what you mean by "out of this file". If $_SESSION['lang'] didn't change in files you included in your script then probably you have included those files before you operated the change on $_SESSION['lang']?

Comment: By "out of this file" i mean after the execution of my function.
I have a <form action="sendLangue.php" method= "post" id="lang">
in my index.php. If i do $_SESSION["lang"]="fr"; in my file sendLangue.php, my echo of $_SESSION["lang"] in this file print "fr" but if I refresh the page the echo $_SESSION["lang"] print nothing. I don't use this variable in an other place i have juste a session_start();